# Certificate chain contained within the public key exposed by RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rabbitmq

I have a c# .net client consuming messages from a RabbitMQ instance (using RabbitMQ.Client) secured using TLS. I got everything working nicely using a self signed certificate.

We've purchased a wildcard certificate from an accredited CA to use going forward. This certificate has actually been signed by an intermediary authority of the Root CA which is trusted by the root CA itself.

Because the intermediary CA will not be trusted by the client machine (the certificate won't be installed into the local machine certificate store), we downloaded a PEM file that contains all the certificates that make up the chain of trust. However, the .net client will not validate this certificate, failing because it cannot establish the chain of trust.

I've had a look around and can find nothing that says .net cannot validate PEM certificates that themselves contain multiple certificates. If I assign a custom delegate to the CertificateValidationCallback property of the RabbitMQ ConnectionFactory I can see that the certificate chain contains only one certificate, which is the certificate that is signed by the intermediate CA.

The client will ultimately be deployed to hundreds of machines so we'd rather not have to deploy the intermediate certificate to all of them and then have to manage them going forward. I'm aware that I can set turn off chain validation by setting the AcceptablePolicyErrors property to SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors but this seems to me to be making things a little less secure.

So, there are two main questions I have here:

1. Does .net cryptographic validation simply not support certificates that contain all the other certificates in the chain (at least if that certificate is a PEM)?
2. Is there a way of working round this?

I'm using .net 4.5.2 although the same problem occurs in .net 4.6.2 and .net 4.7.1.

I'm running it on a Windows 7 machine. The RabbitMQ node is running on a windows 2012 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate the Root CA certificate and Intermediate CA certificate (both `pem` format) into a single file, and use that as the `cacertfile` for RabbitMQ. The Erlang VM should then present both certificates during the handshake phase of session establishment and they should be used by the .NET TLS/SSL code to verify the server's certificate.

You can use [these instructions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html) to assist in troubleshooting your environment.